# preventing new ajax request while old one is in progress

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to write function that fetches data from server on scroll. I will have to write a function like so...

```
         function onscrollend()
         {
           $.ajax({
         });
         }
```

I am now a bit confused as to how to check for the old `.ajax()` call in progress. so that I can cancel the new one.  I am confused because each time the function is called how can I check the previous call status.. Can I access the variables of the previous call?

Comment: Set a flag. That variable should be defined outside the function.

Comment: well, I thought there might be a solution to check for the previous call without setting flag.

Comment: There can be many ajax calls in progress so if you want to target a particular ajax call then setting a scoped flag is the way to go. Set the flag once ajax call is made and then reset it after ajax call is complete.

Comment: Whatever you do, you have to persist information between function calls, which you can only do by using a variable *outside* of the function. So it's basically a flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.ajax()` returns a [promise](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/) which exposes the `readyState` attribute, so you could just assign the return value of your `$.ajax()` call to a variable and inspect its `readyState`

```
var xhr = {};
function onscrollend() {
  if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
    xhr = $.ajax({
      // ..
    });
  }
}
```

Then the ajax call will only fire if the previous one is done (`readyState == 4`).

Comment: FWIW, the fact that the returned value is a promise is irrelevant. The `readyState` property is part of the XMLHTTPRequest API, not the Promise API.

Comment: why you set the `readyState` to zero in advance any unexpected behavior??

Comment: @FelixKling I said "exposes the attribute" (of the xhr), not "has an attribute of the promise API", and insofar as he is using jquery for ajax and not building his own vanilla xhr object it is perfectly relevant. [For backward compatibility with XMLHttpRequest, a jqXHR object will expose the following properties and methods: readyState, etc.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: @whatever just to avoid a TypeError exception for the first iteration. Checking an attribute of an undefined value would croak.

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to point this out explicitly, since it can be easily misunderstood the way you wrote it.

Comment: `var xhr =  {};` would suffice btw.

Comment: Thanks @swornabsent actually I was expecting this reply but I was confused with how to access the current xhr request and store it in a variable... did not thing $.ajax will be returning it.. :D

Answer (score 1):

You can set a flag like so:

```
var inProgress = false;
function onscrollend() {
    if (inProgress) return;
    inProgress = true;
    $.ajax(...).always(function() {
        inProgress = false;
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes Felix Nice solution but I was expecting something similar to the @swornabsent solution..